# SyntaxHighlighter v3.0.83 source code

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

I wanted to play with SyntaxHighlighter so I downloaded the lastest version from http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/. The src/shCore.js file which is a unpacked/unencoded version does not seem to work when I change from scripts/shCore.js to src/shCore.js in the index.html that come with the download.

Does anyone know why or know where I can get a working source code so I can have a play.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Yes. SyntaxHighlighter version 3.0.83 requires [Steven Levithan's XRegExp.js library ver 1.5.0](http://xregexp.com/). The compressed version of SH which works (`scripts/shCore.js` 16,175 bytes), has XRegexp.js built-in. However, the uncompressed version, (`src/shCore.js` 43,502 bytes) will not work until you place a copy of XRegExp.js into the same folder (It is not included in the src folder in the download file.)

Note that if you download the [full source archive](https://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Home), this includes the uncompressed `XRegExp.js` file and will allow you to play around with it and compile/compress it if you want.

Note also, that there is a pretty wicked bug in SyntaxHighlighter which causes it to get confused and incorrectly colorize code. I have written an article describing the bug, and how to fix it. See: [Fixing the SyntaxHighlighter 3.0.83 Parser Bug](http://jmrware.com/articles/2011/sh-bug/SyntaxHighlighterBug.html). I notified the author about the bug but an official fix has not yet been implemented.

This answer is a bit late, but I still hope it may helps someone...

Comment: Remember to explicitly load the "XRegExp.js" file before "shCore.js" if you are using the uncompressed version.

Answer (score 2):

excellent adding!

for debugging, *go to wp-content\plugins\syntax-highlighter-compress\syntax-highlighter-compress.php*

and add  the following line to wp_shc_head() :

```
    <!-- START: Syntax Highlighter ComPress -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://xregexp.com/xregexp.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

These days, v.2.0.0 broke the Syntax Highlighter code, so be sure to include both:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xregexp.com/xregexp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xregexp.com/addons/backcompat.js"></script>
```